# Registration protection after windows reinstall

Tags: c#, windows, registration

I have made an application registration process in c# which takes the MaccAddress , VolumeSerialNumber of disc and merge them. And then it is stored in a install.dll file which is important to launch the application. And i have placed one more file in system32 folder (systemapplication.dll) that keeps record of the application installation.

So process is like that when a user install the application, the application gets the mac address and volume serial number and store them in install.dll. And installation log is created in the system 32 file. So if the user want to reinstall then it prevent him to reinstall after the trial period is over.

Now this structure has a week point that if user reinstall the windows then the file in system32 folder is deleted and there is no record of the previous installation. So I want to ask if there is any method by which i can store the application installation permanently. So it can prevent user to install it again even after windows reinstallation?

Thank You!

Comment: I think only way would be if you store this data on your own server and require online registration. Note that it will fail if user changes mac address which is easy.

Comment: I had that idea before, but online registration won't work if user don't have internet.

Comment: Yes but note that this is not a problem for windows. Online registration is default way to do it but there are other ways like phone or mail that can be used in such cases. The point is you cannot store something in someones computer that the owner would not be able to delete.